# switchView to previous View causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, gluon-mobile

I am creating a MultiView-project with gluon mobile and the problem occurs when I'm switching to a `View` which I already used before.

This specific view is my `HOME_VIEW`, so it is called the first time when the app is launched:

"Main"-class with declaration of the View:

```
public class GluonApplication extends MobileApplication {

    public static final String START_VIEW = HOME_VIEW; 
    public static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "Login View";
    //other views

    @Override
    public void init() {
        addViewFactory(START_VIEW, () -> new StartView());
        addViewFactory(LOGIN_VIEW, () -> new LoginView());
        //other views

        DrawerManager.buildDrawer(this);
        //other code
    }
```

class `StartView`. The content of the View is set according to a variable but in this case only the part surrounded by `else{}` is important.

```
public class StartView extends View {

    public StartView() {
  getStylesheets().add(StartView.class.getResource("start.css").toExternalForm());

        LoginSpace lspace = new LoginSpace();
        setCenter(lspace);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
        appBar.setTitleText("Login");
        appBar.setDisable(true);
        appBar.setVisible(false);
    }

    class LoginSpace extends VBox {

        TextField name;
        TextField pass;

        public LoginSpace() {
            g.p("set LoginSpace",2);
            String s = null;

            if(KopfrechenTrainer.getLoggedIn()) {
                //code
            }
            else {  
            HBox h = new HBox(10.0);
            name = new TextField();
            pass = new TextField();
            Button login = new Button("Anmelden");
            Button reg = new Button("Neu registrieren");

            name.setFloatText("Nutzername");
            pass.setFloatText("Passwort:");
            login.setOnAction(e -> onLogin());
            reg.setOnAction(e -> onReg());

            h.getChildren().addAll(login, reg);
            h.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            getChildren().addAll(name, pass, h);
            KopfrechenTrainer.initKT();

            setSpacing(25);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            Insets pad = new Insets(20,50,20,50);
            setPadding(pad);
            }
        }

        private void onContinue() {
            //code
        }

        private void onLogin() {
            g.p("button_login pressed",2);
        String name = this.name.getText();
        String pass = this.pass.getText();
        boolean logIn = KopfrechenTrainer.checkLogin(name, pass);
        if (logIn) {
            this.name.setText(null);
            this.pass.setText(null);
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("Login View");
        }
        else { 
            Alert fault = new Alert(AlertType.NONE, "Nutzername oder Passwort ist nicht korrekt. " + 
                    "Bitte versuche es erneut oder registriere dich neu.");
            fault.showAndWait();
        }
        }
```

The `START_VIEW` is not listed in the `NavigationDrawer`, I don't know if that is of importance. Normally, the `LOGIN_VIEW` is called from the `START_VIEW`:

```
import static com.gluonapplication.GluonApplication.START_VIEW;
//other imports

public class LoginView extends View {

    public LoginView() {
        //...
        HomeSpace hspace = new HomeSpace();
        setCenter(hspace);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
        appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
        appBar.setTitleText("Startseite");
        appBar.setDisable(false);
    }

    class HomeSpace extends VBox {

        public HomeSpace(){
            g.p("set HomeSpace", 2);

            Label welcome = new Label("Herzlich wilkommen "+KopfrechenTrainer.getName()+"!");
            Button logout = new Button("Abmelden");
            Button leave = new Button("Abmelden und beenden");
            Button quit = new Button("Beenden");

            logout.setOnAction(e -> onLogout());
            leave.setOnAction(e -> onLeave());
            quit.setOnAction(e -> onQuit());

            getChildren().addAll(welcome, logout, quit, leave);
            setSpacing(25);
            setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        private void onLogout() { 
            KopfrechenTrainer.logout();
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(START_VIEW);//this line is of importance!

        }

        private void onLeave() {
            //code
        }

        private void onQuit() {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

When the button logout is pressed, the View switches to `START_VIEW` but at the same time the following error is debugged:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.z.layoutChildren(SourceFile:159)
    at com.gluonhq.impl.charm.a.b.b.y.layoutChildren(SourceFile:23)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.layoutChildren(Control.java:578)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$29(Toolkit.java:398)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:397)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:424)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:518)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$403(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any button action on the new START_VIEW fails and just a white screen is displayed.

I have no idea why this happens and I have already build a similar test-app which works perfectly! Thanks in advance for any ideas how to solve that problem!

Comment: Is this exception happening on desktop or when you test on mobile? So I can understand the flow, when you start the app, you are not logged in, so you fill the user/pass, and click the login button? What brings you to the Login View? When you log out, it goes to the home view, and the null pointer seems to be related to the TextFields. Can you add a listener to the `TextField::textProperty` and print out its content while you try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JoséPereda Oh, I see, there was a little mistake in my Question, I deleted the content of the method ´onLogin()´ instead of ´on continue()´. I'm testing on desktop. You start the app and fill in name an password. Then you click the login button, then the method onLogin() brings you to "Login View" which seems to be the "Home" of the application. And there is the logout button which causes the error. I will try that thing with the TextFields later. How can I add this listener?

Comment: @JoséPereda Found the problem: when I change `this.name.setText(null); this.pass.setText(null);` to `this.name.setText(""); this.pass.setText("");` everything works fine